# AS3 error 2025 upon game restart

Tags: actionscript-3, argument-error

everything in my game runs smoothly, up until the point i die and click to restart the game. when i do the next time the character collides with a bomb it returns;

> ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child
>   of the caller.    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
>     at MethodInfo-34()

Comment: Right now your question doesn't give anyone enough information to be answered (properly).  Please show your code (specifically `MethodInfo-34`).  The error happens when you've removed something from the stage/parent and then try and `removeChild` it again.    Also show how you create the character/bomb (if not in MethodInfo-34)

Comment: what is MethodInfo-34 actually referring to, im new to AS3 and havent actually labelled a variable or anything method 34, thanks

Comment: What is your IDE?  FlashPro?  MethodInfo usually refers to annonymous functions that are auto generated.  So you're 34th anonymously declared function.  Basically just look for the chunk of code where you do `removeChild`. Or post it all...

Comment: maybe is a decompiled swf

Comment: Start by posting the code where you create/instantiate your character and bomb (and where you use them with `addChild`).   Then show your code where they collide and you `removeChild` them.

Comment: thanks for the help, i've figured out i was being silly, i was continuing to try and removeChild from an array source even when the array contained nothing.

Comment: Great, then either update your question with the code and post your resolution as an answer, or delete the question (as it's not useful to any future visitor in it's current state)